# How to launch Notepad++ from the Cygwin command line via an alias?

Tags: bash, quoting, alias

This is what I tried.

```
$ alias n++='(cd `dirname $1`; "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" `basename $1`)'
alias n++='(cd `dirname $1`; "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" `basename $1`)'
history -a;

$ n++ /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
n++ /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf'
history -a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
notepadplusplus() {
    cd `dirname $1`
    "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" `basename $1`
    cd -
}
alias n++=notepadplusplus
```